# Replacement Rule doesn't pass captures through

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

I'm trying to make a function to take a set of Lines (as might be generated by a number of Mathematica library functions) and turn them into SVG code, as follows:

```
SVGLine[y0_, z0_, y1_, z1_] := 
 "<path d=\"M" <> 
  Fold[ToString[#1] <> " " <> ToString[#2] &, "", 
   N@{y0, z0, y1, z1}] <> "\" \\>"

SVGXProject[lines__] := 
 lines /. Line[{{_, y0_, z0_}, {_, y1_, z1_}}] -> 
   SVGLine[y0, z0, y1, z1]
```

Buuut it's not working: the replacement rule matches the `Line[{...}]`s properly, but doesn't actually pass in the values into my function:

```
In[113]:= SVGXProject[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Edges", "Lines"]]

Out[113]= {{"<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>", 
  "<path d=\"M y0 z0 y1 z1\" \\>"}}
```

It certainly seems this should be the same as, oh,

```
In[114]:= {a^2, b^3, c^4, d^5} /. x_^n_ -> n x

Out[114]= {2 a, 3 b, 4 c, 5 d}
```

but clearly it's not; what's going on?

Comment: do you get the correct result if you replace `Rule (->)` with `RuleDelayed (:>)` in your definition of `SVGXProject`?

Comment: ... yes, in fact I do. But why would that make a difference in this case? Or is the right hand side evaluated *immediately, even before the variables are substituted in* without the delay?

Comment: exactly: [Rule Delayed >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html):   _-> evaluates when it is first entered; :> when it is used:_

Comment: ... that's weird. Well, anyway, thanks - if you write that up into an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rule Delayed & Rule  >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html):

> *-> evaluates when it is first entered; :> when it is used*

So, if you replace `Rule (->)` with `RuleDelayed (:>)` in your definition of `SVGXProject`,

```
SVGXProject[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Edges", "Lines"]]
```

gives
[image]